# Encode string in HTML Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have a string and I need to encode it in html.
For example ">" becomes "& gt;"
In C# I do

```
string stringEncoded = System.Net.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
```

How can I do the same thing in Swift?

Comment: I had already seen that page. I do not need to encode the text for a url. The code you linked transforms <?php aaa ?> to %3C%3F aaa %3F%3E. instead the symbol "<" will become "&gt ;"

Answer (score 3):

Might be extremely late by now... At the moment I am doing it like this

```
    let html = "<pre>something</pre>"
    var result = html.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString: "&amp;", options: nil, range: nil)
    result = result.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "&quot;", options: nil, range: nil)
    result = result.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "&#39;", options: nil, range: nil)
    result = result.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "&lt;", options: nil, range: nil)
    result = result.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "&gt;", options: nil, range: nil)
    print(result)
```

Comment: wow, seriously? give me a negative point for a lower case 'at'?

Comment: for instance, @ has to be encoded in &#64;